# How to root Samsung Galaxy Alpha SM-G850A?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting, samsung

Seems I have searched vastly across the internet to no avail.

So far, I've tried using a CF-auto-root file with Odin 3, and vroot, neither of which worked. The only helpful thread I've found was an XDA thread from may 2015 which still did not seem to help

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-alpha/help/want-to-to-root-alpha-sm-g850a-t3107199/

The only other resource I've found were several forums and websites that link back to the same blog that claims to have rooted the phone, but the download file is labeled as malicious by chrome and there is no conformation by anyone that it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to unlock the bootloader before doing this process. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822055324/https://www.unlock-bootloaderb.xyz/2015/11/samsung-galaxy-alpha-6573.html) is tutorial.

As you mentioned above about *odin* , it means you know how to work with odin. Now just download [this CWM](https://s.basketbuild.com/filedl/devs?dev=rutvikrvr&dl=rutvikrvr/slte/cwm/cwm_slte-301014-1339.tar) recovery file and flash it using Odin.
Now download this flashable [SuperSu zip.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b55kznq64bx75d3/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.34.zip?dl=0). Move this SuperSu zip to your sd card. Now you have to boot in recovery mode after flashing CWM recovery. In recovery mode install this zip file and reboot.

This is the best way to root any android.

Comment: Am getting "recovery.img" followed by "NAND Write start!!!" when flashing using the PDA option. Strange... This actually happened when attempting to install the CF-auto-root file using AP.

Comment: Did Odin showed _pass_? It is so as it writes recovery partition with this recovery.

Comment: No, it shows _fail_ with the line "Complete(Write) operation failed. following with "Added!".

Comment: You need to be in 1. download mode, 2. USB debugging mode must be clicked. Other thing may be driver problem. So, you must find an appropriate driver for your device.

Comment: All of these are correct as well as my device driver. Still get the same error. Side note, I did use an earlier version of Odin 3.04, so I could have access to the PDA option, which is not provided in version 3.10.x. could this matter at all? I don't know of another way to flash a recovery.

Comment: Can't say too much but it doesn't matter if you choose AP which is equivalent to PDA.

Comment: @Neuromeda Have you tried using the correct version (whatever is referenced in the guides you've researched/been provided) and just modifying the `.ini`/`.cfg` file to enable whatever option is greyed out?

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer option. Turn on OEM unlock and erase all data.

Start mobile in download mode.

You get custom operating system warning, continue with it.

Extract Odin on computer and start Odin app. Connect Samsung mobile to computer.  KingoRoot work well with KitKat 4 android rooting.

Odin will find Samsung mobile. Click on AP tab and give path to auto root file.

Mobile is rooted then you can see green mark.

Mobile restart automatically.